# Why Hangfire job break when try to use NLog service?

Tags: fatal-error, nlog, hangfire

My boss got error on his laptop with this stacktrace:

```
Fatal on LAPTOP-BGTGSTJU: Exception occurred in NLog
    2018-01-28 11:39:33.1419 Fatal error occurred during execution of 'Worker #b261e15e' process. It will be stopped. See the exception for details.
    | Exception occurred in NLog Void <Write>b__0(System.Exception)
    at NLog.LoggerImpl.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Write>b__0(Exception ex)
    at NLog.Internal.SingleCallContinuation.Function(Exception exception)
    at NLog.Targets.MailTarget.ProcessSingleMailMessage(List`1 events)
    at NLog.Targets.MailTarget.Write(AsyncLogEventInfo[] logEvents)
    at NLog.Targets.MailTarget.Write(AsyncLogEventInfo logEvent)
    at NLog.Targets.Target.WriteAsyncLogEvent(AsyncLogEventInfo logEvent)
    at NLog.LoggerImpl.WriteToTargetWithFilterChain(TargetWithFilterChain targetListHead, LogEventInfo logEvent, AsyncContinuation onException)
    at NLog.LoggerImpl.Write(Type loggerType, TargetWithFilterChain targets, LogEventInfo logEvent, LogFactory factory)
    at NLog.Logger.WriteToTargets(LogLevel level, String message, Exception ex)
    at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , String , Exception )
    at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid3[T0,T1,T2](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
    at Hangfire.Logging.LogProviders.NLogLogProvider.NLogLogger.LogException(LogLevel logLevel, Func`1 messageFunc, Exception exception)
    at Hangfire.Logging.LogProviders.NLogLogProvider.NLogLogger.Log(LogLevel logLevel, Func`1 messageFunc, Exception exception)
    at Hangfire.Logging.LoggerExecutionWrapper.Log(LogLevel logLevel, Func`1 messageFunc, Exception exception)
    at Hangfire.Server.AutomaticRetryProcess.Execute(BackgroundProcessContext context)
    at Hangfire.Server.ServerProcessExtensions.Execute(IServerProcess process, BackgroundProcessContext context)
    at Hangfire.Server.InfiniteLoopProcess.Execute(BackgroundProcessContext context)
    at Hangfire.Server.ServerProcessExtensions.Execute(IServerProcess process, BackgroundProcessContext context)
    at Hangfire.Server.ServerProcessExtensions.RunProcess(IServerProcess process, BackgroundProcessContext context)
```

Can anyone help me to start understand what happen?
It looks like some job failed and it tried to retry … And it failed fatal then.
I looked at [this resource](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/1404) with pointing that this could be Hangfire bug.

Comment: Have you looked at the NLog internal logger? ( https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging ) Have you made sure to configure throwexceptions=false in the NLog-config? ( https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file ). Maybe the exception is just because the boss laptop don't authenticate or connect correctly against the smtp-mail server? (Maybe no valid network connection)

Comment: Thanks, @RolfKristensen. We already found previous developer left `throwexceptions=true`. We believe this is solution. Since, we got this error seldom, we will just take some time to see will it happen again.